# PHP download multiple files in curl or by any other way at the same time

Tags: php, curl, httprequest

I need to download many files from many website like e.g. 10 files which usually takes (8-9)
seconds to download all the files.

What i want is to make the request simultaneously (parallel) so that the job finishes in (1-2) seconds.

I know use of curl in single requests and multiple requests. but the request of 10 files should start at the same time

```
e.g. 02:38:14 // all the request started at this time
```

I have a lot of bandwidth so parallel download will not be a problem.

is this possible in curl or by any other way ?

Comment: Do you want to do this in PHP or generally speaking, e. g. in the shell?

Comment: @ntaso shell or PHP both of them are okay

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in the shell, you can simply send a command to the background with `&`. This should work:

```
for I in `cat urls.txt`; do curl $I & done
```

This loops through all urls in a file called `urls.txt` and executes `curl URL &` on them. The `&` tells curl to run in the background.

Comment: i already tried this from loop in php exec('curl ' . $url_list[$i] . '> filename.txt &'); but i am getting some url content **empty**.

Comment: Looks like you overwrite the contents of filename.txt? Or is filename.txt also dynamically created in your script? Otherwise use `>> filename.txt`. Do all processes finish correctly? Otherwise check `curl_multi_init`.

Comment: filename and every thing is dynamically created